# Should we have a biglm tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are 56 questions about biglm package (or about biglm funcion) in R. Should we have a tag for them?

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=biglm+is%3Aquestion

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's different from the [lm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lm) package, so I added [biglm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biglm) to one of the questions asking about it. You can add it to other questions that are specifically about that package.

As always, when editing tags, please make any other necessary edits to each question that you update.